Logout button not working which is placed in sidebar in react component
I am building a web application using react and node.js. In this i successfully implemented user signup and login pages with authentication using JWT. In my home page(after login) which has a profile section of user at top right. I implemented Logout button inside the profile section.
But i don't know why it is not working.
Logout.jsx:
      `import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
       import axios from "axios";

       const Logout = () => {
       const navigate = useNavigate();

       const handleLogout = async () => {
       try {
         const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:3000/api/auth/logout");
         console.log(response.data);
         localStorage.removeItem("token");
         navigate("/login");
       }
       catch(error) {
         console.error(error);
           }
       };

       return (
       <button type="submit" onClick={handleLogout} className="bg-red-600 text-white px-4 py-2      rounded-md shadow-md hover:bg-red-700">Logout</button>
       );
        };

       export default Logout;`

I created a separate component Logout.jsx and imported into Sidebar.jsx file.
Someone help me please
Implemented Logout.jsx component and imported into Sidebar.jsx component in my project.
But it is not working and not responding.

The question requires https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . It's unknown why it's not working on your side. The problem needs to be isolated to either front or back end

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
